# echoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.8.4

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I am on Ubuntu. And want to install echoe gem. For this running `sudo gem install echoe` command.

and getting

```
ERROR:  Error installing echoe:
    echoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.8.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
```

My `RubyGems version is 1.8.17`, got this using

`gem -v` giving me `1.8.17`

Why I am getting this error message, I'm already having `RubyGems version >= 1.8.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be that you used rvm to install your ruby. If you now use `sudo gem install ...` you are activating the system ruby install which is outdated. Try using `gem install ...` or if that doesn't work `ruby -S gem install ...`.

Comment: yes i used rvm to install ruby, thanks @three last one worked for me.

Comment: then you might have a problem with your rvm install too. You probably messed up somewhere by not including rvm in you bashrc file or using sudo elsewhere. I'd recommend reinstalling and not using sudo inbetween.